# Table and post values

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using Wordpress with the Advanced Custom fields plugin. My template looks like:

```
<table>
  <?php 
    query_posts('post_type=meeting');
    if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . the_field('city') . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . the_field('time') . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
  ?>
  <!-- Do stuff -->
  <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
</table>
```

This works, but for some reason my markup now looks like this:

```
<table>
  <tr>
     <td></td>Yellowstone<td></td>5:30 A.M.
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'meeting', 'posts_per_page' => 10 );
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
?>

<table>
  <tr>
     <td><?php the_field('city'); ?></td>
     <td><?php the_field('time'); ?></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

The reason why your code is not working is because it should look like this - single quotes will display things almost completely "as is."

```
echo '<td>' . the_field('city') . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . the_field('time') . '</td>';
```

Within your echo example above, i would have done it like so - double quotes will display a host of escaped characters (including some regexes), and variables in the strings will be evaluated.

```
$city = the_field('city');
$cityTime = the_field('time');

echo "<td> $city </td>";
echo "<td> $cityTime </td>";
```